# Как осуществить циклический сдвиг?

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Задано 4 байтовое число, с 10 по 4 биты сдвинуть влево на 3 разряда.

Answer (score 2):

Считая младший бит с номером 0, примерно так (не компилировал, просто идея).

```
unsigned int shift4_10(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int b = x & 0x7F0;
    unsigned int r = ((b << 3)|(b>>4)) &0x7F0;
    return (x&~0x7F0)|r;
}
```

Тот случай, когда проще написать решение, чем объяснить словами, как решать... :(